# Literature on Business Value Added (BVA)

Tags: literature-research

I don't know if this is the correct community to ask this question, but I did not find a community directly related to lean manufacturing.

Recently I came across a term I haven't heard before: BVA (Business Value Added). I am writing my Master's Thesis, and I didn't come across this term during my literature review. However, this is relevant to the scope of my work, and I need to find a good book related to BVA.
My review covered a lot of the "old bibles": *The Toyota Way*, *Lean Thinking*, etc.. And none of them mentions it.

Does anyone know of a useful reference covering BVA?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! I changed your BVA from "Business Added-Value" to "Business Value Added (or Add)". Because when you search that's how the acronym is defined. If this was not what you had in mind, feel free to revert.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! Business Value Added makes more sense, thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Business Value Added is a general concept and could be translated as a specific term/definition in the manufacturing, services or another real-applications era. For example, in the manufacturing field, it might be defined as, any improvement in each step of producing a product.

Also, it can be represented as, value-added, measures the amount of wealth created by a company and it is important since it reflects the ability of companies to provide their customers with what they want and are prepared to pay for. It provides a broader perspective on a company's economic contribution than operating profit.

I hope the below references would be helpful.

- [Value-added Management with Design of Experiments](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789401042550?utm_campaign=3_pier05_buy_print&utm_content=en_08082017&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=google_books#otherversion=9789401105774)
- [Value Added Scoreboard - Definition and Calculation of Value Added Business Performance](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=9783640901791&i=stripbooks&linkCode=qs)

Comment: It appears so. I only found a BVA definition in the lean.org website, not in any book. I will take a look at those references. Thanks for the input!